# Surfaces with Planar Coordinate Curves and Orthogonal Carrier Planes

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, coordinate-systems, surfaces

Let $\mathbf{x}:U\subset\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular parametric surface with the following properties:

- conjugate net: $\langle \mathbf{x}_{uv}, \mathbf{x}_u\times\mathbf{x}_v\rangle = 0$,
- planar coordinate curves: $\det\left(\mathbf{x}_u,\mathbf{x}_{uu},\mathbf{x}_{uuu} \right) = 0$ and $\det\left(\mathbf{x}_v,\mathbf{x}_{vv},\mathbf{x}_{vvv} \right) = 0$,
- orthogonal carrier planes: $\langle \mathbf{x}_u\times\mathbf{x}_{uu},\mathbf{x}_v\times\mathbf{x}_{vv}\rangle = 0$.

For simplicity, one would probably also require the *nondegeneracy conditions*:

$$\mathbf{x}_u\times\mathbf{x}_{uu} \neq 0\quad\quad\quad  \mathbf{x}_v\times\mathbf{x}_{vv} \neq 0.$$

**Example:**

The **scale-rotation** surfaces:
$$
\mathbf{x}(u,v) =  
 \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 
\mu\left( v \right) \cos \left( \theta
 \left( v \right)  \right) &-\mu \left( v \right) \sin \left( \theta
 \left( v \right)  \right) &0\\ \mu \left( v
 \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( v \right)  \right) &\mu\left( v
 \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( v \right)  \right) &0
\\ 
0&0&1\end {array} \right]\,
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
f(u)\\
0\\
g(u)
\end{array}
\right], 
$$
where $\mu: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^+ $ and $f(u) \neq 0 $,
fits into this class of surfaces.

**My Question:**

I would like to determine the parametric surfaces possessing the above properties. My knowledge of PDE is very limited and I would appreciate answers putting me on the right track.

**1st Edit (July 2022):**
Does a generic regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, locally support such a parametrization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the answer to this question was more than just a simple quick one. One can find the answer in the following paper:

[Isometric Deformations of Smooth and Discrete T-surfaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/2302.08925)

In this paper the authors describe such surfaces in detail. They also mention their polygonal counterparts (as discrete surfaces) and study the isometric deformations of both scenarios.